# Add/replace a rule in a list of rules based upon the rule's lhs without regard for the rule's rhs

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following lists of rules:

```
{x -> 1, y -> 2}
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 4}
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2}
```

For each list of rules, I would like to add the rule `z -> 3` or replace any rule whose lhs is `z` 
with `z -> 3` .

I am able to get this to work for specific rules, for example `z -> 4`

```
AddReplaceRule[rules_List] :=
 Module[{newRules},
  If [MemberQ[rules, z -> 4],
   newRules = DeleteCases[rules, z -> 4];
   ,
   newRules = rules;
   ];
  Append[newRules, z -> 3]
  ]
```

---

**Results**

*Note I am expecting to see* `{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}` *for all three cases, but that is not the case, since I need to generalize* `z -> 4` *in AddReplaceRule.*

```
In[]:= AddReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2}]
Out[]= {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}

In[]:= AddReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 4}]
Out[]= {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}

In[]:= AddReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2}]
Out[]= {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2, z -> 3}
```

Comment: Note that, if you intend to apply these rules, you can simply `Prepend` your new rule to the list. You will then have rules with the same l.h.s., true, but the new rule will always apply first, just because of the way rule application works. Unless these operations are so frequent that you grow truly huge list of rules, this should work fine. And if you do, you can periodically use `Dispatch` on these rules. You can even set up a wrapper which would do that automatically, which, however, is slightly more complex and may be destroying the purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
r1 = {x -> 1, y -> 2};
r2 = {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 4};
r3 = {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2};
```

An idea could be

```
changeRule[rule : (sym_ -> _)] := Append[
   FilterRules[#, Except[sym]], rule] &
```

So

```
changeRule[z -> 3] /@ {r1, r2, r3}
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {x -> 1, 
>         y -> 2, z -> 3}}

**EDIT**

Other versions avoiding `FilterRules`

```
changeRulesV2[rule_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[#, rule], First[#1] === First[#2] &] &
changeRulesV3[rule : (sym_ -> _)] := 
 Append[DeleteCases[#, sym -> _], rule] &
```

Here's a version that works for several rules at once, inspider by @kguler's comment

```
changeRuleV4[rules : (_ -> _) ..] := 
 Join[FilterRules[#, Except@Alternatives[rules][[All, 1]]], {rules}] &

changeRuleV4[z -> 9, h -> 99][{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 4}]
```

> {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 9, h -> 99}

Comment: Thanks for pointing `FilterRules` that is what I have been looking.  Would have been nice if `FilterRules` was in `Rule`'s SEE ALSO section.

Comment: Nice (+1)... Just a thought: with a slight modification, the same idea can be used for adding/modifying multiple rules: for example, `replaceOrAddRules = Function[{rules, newrules}, FilterRules[rules, Except[Rule[First@#, _] & /@ newrules]]~Join~ newrules]`. Applied as `replaceOrAddRules[#, {z -> 3, x -> 5, w -> 1}] & /@ {r1, r2, r3}` gives `{{y -> 2, z -> 3, x -> 5, w -> 1}, {y -> 2, z -> 3, x -> 5, w -> 1}, {y -> 2, z -> 3, x -> 5, w -> 1}}`.

Comment: @kguler, I don't understand why your pattern `Except[{x->_, y->_}]` works in `FilterRules`, but it does. However, `Except[(x->_)|(y->_)]` doesn't, `Except[x|y]` does (my version, this I get), and `Except[{x, y}]` doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Rojo, I tried to make `Except[...]` to produce something that conforms to the second argument of `FilterRules`, a pattern or a list of patterns. When the second argument of `FilterRules` is a list, all of the following `{x,y}, {x->_,y->_},{x:>_,y},{x->_,y:>_},{x,y->_}` work. If I use any of these inside `Except` I get the expected results. When the second argument is not a list, `x|y` and `Except[x|y]` works. But using `(x->_)|(y->_)` yields `{}`, and the same pattern inside `Except` gives the first argument back. It is indeed puzzling `Except[{x,y}]` did not work in your case.

Comment: @kguler ...weird....weird

Comment: @Rojo, could you try `changeRuleV5[rules : (_ -> _) ..] := 
 Join[FilterRules[#, Except[First /@ {rules}]], {rules}] &` and `changeRuleV6[rules : (_ -> _) ..] :=  Join[FilterRules[#, Except[Thread[First /@ {rules} -> _]]], {rules}]  &`?

Comment: @kguler, the last one is similar to your first one. V5 also works!! I could have sworn that I had tried stuff like Except[{x,y}] and hadn't worked but now they do!

Comment: happens to me all time ... especially when the notebook title is `Untitled-25*` and the cell number is something like `Out[1371]` :)

Comment: @kguler, I had an Untitled-45 I think about an hour ago. However, I rarely get to more than Out[400], usually below 100. I'm an easy `Exit`er

Answer (score 7):

You can use rules to replace rules! Here's an example:

```
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2} /. HoldPattern[z -> _] :> (z -> 3)
(* {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3} *)
```

Now when there isn't a rule involving `z` and you want to add the new one to the existing rules, it becomes a bit more involved and inelegant — you should go with Rojo's solution. Nevertheless, I'll include the following if only to highlight Mathematica's flexibility.

For the general case when there may or may not be a rule involving `z`, the following works (thanks to Rojo for improving):

```
Replace[oldRules, {x___, Longest[PatternSequence[] | (z -> _)], y___} :> {x, newRule, y}]
```

For example:

```
Replace[{x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x___, Longest[PatternSequence[] | (z -> _)], y___} :> {x, z -> 3, y}]
(* {z -> 3, x -> 1, y -> 2} *)
```

This will be slower (at least, for longer lists) due to the use of `BlankNullSequence`.

Comment: He doesn't want to replace only, also add if it isn't there

Comment: Now I like it, +1. But it fails, for example, for {z -> 4, y -> 2, x -> 1}. You can fix it with Longest, as in this alternative that searches only the first level `Replace[{x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x___, Longest[PatternSequence[] | (z -> _)], y___} :> {x, z -> 3, y}]`

Comment: @Rojo How does it fail? I still get `z -> 3` as the first element. The pattern should give empty for `x___`, a match for `HoldPattern[...]` and the remaining for `y___`. The second `z -> _` rule doesn't matter because it won't be applied. But I like your suggestion using `Longest`

Comment: @RM, sorry, I hadn't seen you had considered the fact it sometimes simply prepends

Comment: @Rojo I added your suggestion, which was better than what I had.

Answer (score 4):

Had `FilterRules[]` not been available, I would have done something like this:

```
addReplaceRule[ruleList : {(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..}, newRule : _Rule | _RuleDelayed] := 
 Module[{patt = newRule /. ((a_ -> b_) | (a_ :> b_)) :> ((a -> _) | (a :> _))}, 
  If[FreeQ[ruleList, patt], Append[ruleList, newRule], 
   ruleList /. patt -> newRule]]
```

Try it out:

```
addReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 5}, z -> 3]
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}

addReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2}, z -> 3]
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}

addReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, z :> 3]
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z :> 3}

addReplaceRule[{x -> 1, y -> 2, z :> 3}, z -> 3]
{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

One more way.

`Position` checks where, if at all, there is an existing rule that has the targeted lhs. If such a rule is not in `rules`, `Position` will return `{}` and the `newRule` is appended.
Otherwise, the old rule is replaced by the `newRule`.

```
f[rules_, newRule_] :=
   Module[{pos = Position[rules, (newRule[[1]] -> _)]},
   If[pos == {}, Append[rules, newRule], ReplacePart[rules, pos[[1]] -> newRule]]]
```

So

```
f[#, (z -> 3)] & /@ {{x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 4}, {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 2}}

(* out *)
{{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, {x -> 1, y -> 2,  z -> 3}}
```