# How to update a rule with some new rule?

Tags: replacement, rule

If I have a rule

```
oldRule = {a -> 1, b -> 2}
```

> `{a->1,b->2}`

Then I have a new rule `newRule = {a -> 8, c -> 2}`.How to use it to update my `oldRule`?I hope to get

> `{a->8,b->2,c->2}`

Actually I think the `Union` can implement this target.But it always will choice that small element.I don't know how to control this behavior.

```
Union[{a -> 8, c -> 2}, oldRule, SameTest -> (SameQ @@ Keys[{##}] &)]
```

> `{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 2}`

Or any elegant workaround can do this?

Comment: Are Associations allowed?

Comment: @Kuba Do you mean `<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 2|>`?It's allowed.

Comment: @yode If you define the rules as associations, `Join[oldRule, newRule]` works.

Comment: Related: [5970](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5970/add-replace-a-rule-in-a-list-of-rules-based-upon-the-rules-lhs-without-regard-f)

Comment: Here is a general topic about associations: [How to organically merge nested associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102466/5478)

Comment: Are you restricted to newRule or can you work with something like `newNewRule = oldRule /. (a -> 1) :> (a -> 8) // Append[#, c -> 2] &`?  Also (of course), `({a, b, c} /. newNewRule) == ({a, b, c} /. Join[newRule, oldRule])` (but not equal to `{a, b, c} /. Join[oldRule, newRule]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foo = Normal@*Merge[Last]
```

> ```
> foo@{oldRule, newRule}
> ```

Even this will do:

```
Normal @ <|oldRule, newRule|>
```

here is a link about nested associations:

[How to organically merge nested associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102466/5478)

Answer (score 2):

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[newRule, oldRule], First]
```

> `{a->8,c->2,b->2}`

Or by [Anjan Kumar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19742/anjan-kumar)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145404/how-to-update-a-rule-with-some-new-rule?noredirect=1#comment391039_145404)

```
Normal[Join[<|oldRule|>, <|newRule|>]]
```

> `{a->8,b->2,c->2}`

As my test,the solution based on `Associations` have a better performance

```
oldRule = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[1000, {200000, 2}];
newRule = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[1000, {200000, 2}];
AbsoluteTiming[Normal[Join[<|oldRule|>, <|newRule|>]];]
AbsoluteTiming[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[newRule, oldRule], First];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
Join[newRule,oldRule]
```

is all you need to ensure that the new rules are used because the first rule is only ever used. If you wanted to eliminate redundant rules then

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[newRule, oldRule], #[[1]]&]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Complement` instead of `Union`

```
(#2~Join~Complement[#1, #2, SameTest -> (SameQ @@ Keys[{##}] &)]) &[oldRule, newRule]

(* {c -> 2, a -> 8, b -> 2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered by Rojo, in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5971/731) answer:

```
changeRuleV4[rules : (_ -> _) ..] := 
 Join[FilterRules[#, Except@Alternatives[rules][[All, 1]]], {rules}] &

changeRuleV4[Sequence @@ newRule][oldRule]
```

> `{b -> 2, a -> 8, c -> 2}`

We can also apply his other functions, which were written for the replacement of a single rule, repeatedly:

```
changeRule[rules_, rule : (sym_ -> _)] := 
 Append[FilterRules[rules, Except[sym]], rule]

changeRules[rules_, new_] := Fold[changeRule, rules, new]

changeRules[oldRule, newRule]
```

> `{b -> 2, a -> 8, c -> 2}`

These solutions are slow, especially the second one, but I wanted to show the relation between this post and that other Q&A.